# Hide div having variable dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, php, css, oop

The div is a switch which gets a dynamic ID .
class name is impbtn , id is generated in variable this.impbtn6.id

HTML:

```
<div id="widget-id63032Candy_Eaten_importGoodsBtn" class="impbtn"></div>
```

There are two places hide is required - click and onload
In click event

```
document.getElementById(this.impbtn6.id).style.visibility="hidden";
```

works fine .
I cannot use Document.getelementbyID , as multiple form loads occur and button is not supposed to be hidden then .
So i trued using JQ to access css properties
This

```
jQuery('.impbtn, #this.impbtn6.id').css('visibility',"hidden");
```

works but makes all button in the class invisible . I want to make only this.expbtn6.id invisible not all ids under this class .

I have read each and every page available.Some things Iv unsuccessfully tried (Separately)

```
var vid= this.impbtn6.id;
jQuery("#"+ vid).visibility("hidden");
$('#vid .impbtn').css('visibility',"hidden")
var row2=$(".impbtn").find("div#"+vid);
row2.hide();
$('#vid .impbtn').css('visibility',"hidden");
$('div#vid').css('visibility',"hidden");
$('.impbtn', $("#div" + this.impbtn6.id)).css('visibility',"hidden");
$("#div"+ vid).css('visibility',"hidden");
$("#"+ vid).hide();
$('#vid').css('visibility',"hidden");
row = $('#' + vid);
row.css('visibility',"hidden");
```

I would highly appreciate a reply/comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#this.exportbtn6.id').css('visibility','visible');
```

Comment: I guess you meant $('#this.exportbtn6.id').css('visibility','hidden');. The curly braces return error .That doesnt work. But thanks for trying

Comment: Oh! Sorry for that.. well i have removed the curly braces.. Did it work out well after removing it

Answer (score 0):

your question is a little confusing as you say 
document.getElementById(this.exportbtn6.id).style.visibility="visible";

works fine but this code shows the div, not hides it, and why cannot the same code be used to hide if you use it to show?

then your other snippet that supposedly works:

jQuery('.expbtn, #this.exportbtn6.id').css('visibility',"visible");

cannot work because #this.exportbtn6.id will not resolve to the variable's content inside the double quotes, so i am pretty sure this line will not do anything.

The way to do this correctly is

jQuery('#' + this.exportbtn6.id + '.expbtn').hide();

but i cannot tell for sure as the question is not clear. If my understanding of your question is correct, the above line will do the trick. Keep in mind that the value of "this" will differ based on context, so it maybe that you are referencing the wrong "this".

Comment: My apologies . The code is intended to hide , so I used hidden instead of show in the place you pointed in getelementbyID .<2> Probably thats the reason why it hid all the elements wth class name =expbtn , and gave an illusion of working . <3> I tried your code , But it doesnt hide the div. Iam confused as to why the selector doesnt seem to work .<4> Console.log(this.expbtn6.id)) gives the exact same id in the inspect element , so I dont think I have the wrong reference. Thanks

Comment: @user3261251 is it possible there is something else re-showing the div? can you put an alert right after the hide() to force a pause and see if the div is hidden? also can you console.log(jQuery('#' + this.exportbtn6.id + '.expbtn')[0]) ?

Comment: Its impossible to press the tab and check the button visually . I cant seem to find it in html . <2>console returns not defined for it .<3> tried console.log($('#' + this.exportbtn6.id + '.expbtn').css('visibility')); but that returns not defined as well . Will check the code again .

Comment: @user3261251 is it on a public website i can look at? or you can post a jsfiddle or a more complete working copy of the code?

Comment: Iam afraid thats not possible . Fiddle cannot imitate most of functions and simple execution seems to work on simple html like above .

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
$("#"+this.expbtn6.id).hide();
```

I hope it helps.